# Retornar um input que está dentro de uma função

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho esse código:

```
bebidas = {'Suco de laranja': 5.99, 'Suco de uva': 5.99, 'Suco de açaí': 5.99, 'Coca Cola(lata)': 6.50, 'Vitamina': 7.50}
salgados = {'Coxinha': 5.00, 'Pastel': 7.50, 'Hamburguer': 7.50}
sobremesas = {'Sonho': 2.99,'Bolo de chocolate': 4.99,'Pudim': 6.00,'Salada de frutas': 5.49}
lista = [1,2]
def menu():
ver = input('Você deseja ver o nosso menu?[Sim/Não]')
return ver
menu()
```

Mas não sei como retornar o input para usar a estrutura if nele.

Comment: Você já está retornando.

Comment: Reverti a edição porque o código novo não faz muito sentido e descaracteriza a resposta, poderia explicar melhor o que não entendeu ainda? Aparentemente o uso da IF você já entendeu, ou não?

Comment: Primeiro fiz a edição e depois fui explicar, aí não deu tempo. Estou tentando fazer um loop , mas o input é o que não está sendo reconhecido e acho que por isso o loop não encerra. O problema é como fazer esse input que está dentro da função ser reconhecido. Só que pra esse código novo: def ver():
 veja = input('Você deseja ver o nosso menu?[Sim/Não]')
 while True:
  ver()
  if veja == 'Sim'.lower():
   break

Comment: Ainda não sei como adiciono o código do jeito certo no comentário.

Comment: O IF tem que ir dentro do While, indentado ... mas eu não entendi porque colocou o While, faça como eu fiz no ultimo exemplo, use "recursão" no seu `def`.

Comment: Falta também o `ver()` ser setado em `veja`, deveria ser assim `... True: veja = ver() if veja == ...`

Comment: Usei o último exemplo e funcionou, mas não consegui fazer o loop até que o usuário digite sim

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que deseja, não da para entender qual o uso que você deseja com este loop

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu quero fazer um loop dessa pergunta do menu até que digite sim

Answer (score 3):

Seria algo como:

```
if menu() == "Sim":
    #chama o menu
else:
    #fecha o programa ou outra
```

Todavia isso não seria *case-sensitve*, então pode usar `.lower()`, pois assim se for SIM, sim, Sim, sIm, SIm, sIM e etc vai funcionar, exemplo:

```
def menu():
    ver = input('Você deseja ver o nosso menu?[Sim/Não]')
    return ver.lower()

if menu() == "sim":
    print("Escreveu sim")
else:
    print("Escreveu qualquer outra coisa")
```

Para facilitar também pode usar apenas S e N (o N é relativo, na verdade qualquer coisa que não S e SIM seria não), para isto use o **`in`**:

```
def menu():
    ver = input('Você deseja ver o nosso menu? Para confirmar digite Sim ou S ou Yes ou Y: ')
    return ver.lower()

if menu() in [ "sim", "s", "yes", "y" ]:
    print("Escreveu sim")
else:
    print("Escreveu qualquer outra coisa")
```

---

Se o `input` for usado para outros "comandos" que você irá criar basta usar o **`elif`** (python não tem estrutura de switch/case) e salvar o valor do `input()` em uma variável, assim por exemplo:

```
def meuApp():
    resposta = input('Digite o seu comando: ').lower()

    if resposta == "menu":
        print(
            """1 - Digite "menu" (sem aspas) para abrir o menu novamente\n"""
            """2 - Digite "produtos" (sem aspas) para ver os produtos\n"""
            """3 - Digite "fechar" (sem aspas) para encerrar o programa\n"""
        )
    elif resposta == "produtos":
        print("\n\n\nExibindo os produtos\n\n\n")
    elif resposta == "fechar":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalido")

    meuApp() # deixa o app recursivo

meuApp() #inicia
```